# Standard placeholder text for a business card

Tags: branding, template-design

I would like to know if there is any standard placeholder text for each & every content in a business card?
The content may include

- Name
- Job/position
- Email
- Phone

Comment: I don't think there *is* any standard. Unfortunately, the answer field won't accept the answer 'No.' :)

Comment: No, there is no standard placeholder text for each and every content on a business card.

Comment: http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article9049378.ece/alternates/w620/chen-business-insider.jpg

Comment: Not a duplicate because it's another Stack, but a lot of the same information: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/demo-data-in-screenshots-what-are-the-best-practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no standard, but the important consideration is to make sure you're not using a value of an entity that actually exists. There's an entire Wikipedia article on [placeholder names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name). It covers all kinds of things, including company/organizations and physical addresses.

### Name

"John Smith" or "John Doe" are the first two that come to mind. You could also use a [multiple-use name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-use_name) or use [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language) to target a specific language.

### E-mail / Web Address

You should use one of the reserved example second level domain names as specified by [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606).

> 3. Reserved Example Second Level Domain Names
>
> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) also currently has the following second level domain names reserved which can be used as examples.
>
> - example.com
> - example.net
> - example.org

This will prevent you from using a domain or e-mail address that actually exists. That document also lists TLDs that are reserved if you'd like to use something a little more interesting, such as "johnb@stackexchange.example".

### Telephone / Fax

Some countries have [fictitious telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_telephone_number). For the US: not *every* number prefixed with 555 is safe to use, so be careful there!

> Not all numbers that begin with 555 are fictional—for example, 555-1212 is one of the standard numbers for directory assistance throughout the United States and Canada. In fact, only 555-0100 through 555-0199 are now specifically reserved for fictional use; the other numbers have been reserved for actual assignment, with the notable exception of the 800 area code where only 800-555-0199 is reserved.<sup>[[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number))</sup>

Comment: There's also the [Trello login](https://trello.com/login) approach, of using entertaining fictional names that are common to the use of your audience. Though you *do* have to make sure it's done in good taste.

Comment: @Wayne hah, I use a password manager so I'd never noticed those placeholders. That's a neat idea

Comment: @JohnB my favorite is that they have `e.g. *******` in the password block. I looked in the DOM, though (and maybe with JS?), and couldn't see any *actual* password. I'm not sure if that makes it better or worse :P

Comment: I've noticed at least one movie use NXX-1XX-XXX as a fictitious phone number, on the premise that all US phone numbers are required to have the form NXX-NXX-XXXX, where N is 2-9.  Since a number of areas no longer allow seven-digit dialing, it would be possible for them to have numbers whose fourth digit is a "1", but I don't know that any do.

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard of any standard placeholder text but you can use something like this

Name: John Smith

Owner (I wouldn't use the words job/position, that is implied)

Email: <strike>name@yourcompany.com</strike> name@example.com

website: <strike>yourcompany.com</strike> example.com

It was brought to my attention that **yourcompany.com is a registered domain name which should not be used** in any example mockup. It is best to use a reserved domain name: example.com, which is mentioned in JohnB's answer.

Phone: 123.456.7891 or I have used 555.555.555 or however you want to format the phone number.

I don't have any sources to back up if this is "standard" placeholder text.

Comment: This is as close to a "standard" for this as you will probably find, generally with some minor variations. If you were to include a physical address, I commonly see: 123 Anywhere St., Anytown, USA 123456.

Comment: I'd recommend editing this answer to replace "yourcompany.com" (which does some nasty redirects) to "example.com".

Comment: example.com is the standard example domain, and should be used anywhere you're using example text. For ip addresses there's [192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2), and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3)](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/19874/1655)

Comment: @WayneWerner: Can one legitimately use arbitrary subdomains of `example.com` for similar purposes?  For example, `yourcompany.example.com`?

Comment: @supercat You could but why would you unless the project was dealing with subdomains? This will most likely confuse a client. Using any text for the subdomain followed by .example.com will be fine as it will not be associated with any usable domains.